# How do you know if you're supposed to get the Electorate badge?

Tags: support, badges

I just reached 600 votes, but I wasn't awarded the [Electorate badge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/badges/28/electorate). How do I find out what my ratio of Qustion:Answer votes are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/badges/28/electorate)

> Voted on 600 **questions** and 25% or more of total votes are on questions.

So you currently voted on 380 question and 226 answer (606 total). You still have to vote on 220 question to get the badge.

see also : [Electorate badge rules?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34340/electorate-badge-rules)

Answer (score 2):

To see your question/answer ratio, you can look at your profile.  Under your list of answers, you will see a "votes cast" section.

This section breaks out your total up and down votes, and your votes by questions and answers:

[image: vote count]

Comment: no [Freehand Circle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775)?

Comment: I debated it, but my freehand circles are abysmal :(